# Custom rest api / client security scheme

Tags: javascript, rest

Right off the bat, I'd like to know if there is a widely used library or standard that I could adopt to replace my "custom" scheme.  I am certain that I, as one person, cannot produce something better than a community produced library.

That said, I am a security novice, and while reviewing other implementations did not find one that seemed to suit my exact needs.  It was probably right under my nose and I didn't understand it.

I am developing a restful api and a javascript client.  I intend to honestly implement rest and go stateless, meaning no server side sessions.  All the information to answer any request must be passed by client to the server as part of the request.

The security solution needs to provide protection against a third party remote attacker that is moderately to seriously resolute.

I do not intend to protect against an attacker that is in physical custody of either the client or server systems.

So, with all that in mind, here is my custom :( solution.

- Site-wide HTTPS
- At registration to the service, the user's password is passed 'clear' to the server where it is stored in a salted sha-3 hash.
- Upon login, the javascript client does not pass the user id and password to the server.  Instead, it generates a random string and stores that in the window.name space.  It then uses this string as a passphrase to perform 256bit AES encryption on the name and password, storing this cipher text in a cookie.  This cookie has a life of 1 hour.
- Henceforth, all API calls require that the client access the window.name string, decrypt the cookie, and pass the username/password 'clear' to the server.  A unix-epoch timestamp is also passed.
- The server, upon receiving any request, retrieves the user's salt, performs a sha-3 hash on the password, and compares it to the stored value in the db.  It also ensures that the timestamp is within 60 seconds of the server time.
- If those checks pass, the client is considered authenticated for that single request.

I'm definitely not a security expert, but I figure this forum is.  Whatever you suggest I will take to heart.

Comment: SHA3 for hashing passwords is a big no no, have a look here http://cloud101.eu/blog/2013/09/14/about-secure-password-hashing/

Comment: Why do you say you're going stateless and don't use server-side sessions, then you create your own server-side session scheme, all you do differently is generate nonce on your own and pass it along in response body as well as response header (i.e. you split the session key in two parts)? You're contradicting yourself there. And you still pass user password in plaintext on each new request, so why not stick with that alone if you're using HTTPS? What specific threat vector are you looking to thwart against, because I don't see any benefit to your scheme, it only complicates it for you?

Comment: @TildalWave I'm not sure how I'm creating a server side session?  The nonce is generated on the client and passed to the server.  I may be misunderstanding you.  Sorry.  And I definitely want to avoid complicating it for myself :)

Comment: You're right, I misread one part. Still, I don't see how this added complexity adds anything to the security of your scheme. If client is required to keep the same browser window open he used to login, then what's the difference if you simply store his password directly in a JavaScript variable? Or use client storage? It would help if you tell us what attack vectors you were hoping to prevent with your scheme. You're still sending password after you decrypt it, so what's preventing some malicious script to collect it before the request is made?

Comment: @TildalWave I guess I don't know how to answer the attack vector question cause I'm unsure what that is.  I mean, I want the site to be hardened against replay attacks, impersonation, man-in-the-middle, XSS, and whatever else is important.  ... About the javascript variable, I would do that but there's a page load after the login before accessing the application - unless I were to combine the pages.  That's where the window.name comes in.  Even then, it seemed a bit crude to store their password clear text in window.name, thus the encrypted cookie.

Comment: You're not protecting against any of those with your added complexity. HTTPS does that for you so far for some of them, but you're still sending password with each new request, and it doesn't mean a thing what you do to it in between requests. The way you do it, it would be exactly equal to storing the password in the cookie or local storage then, if window reloads in between requests. That local encryption/decryption only gives you false sense of security and makes everything complicated for no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: @TildalWave Good point, encrypting the cookie does seem worthless.  I had wanted to protect the cookie from other domains, but ... other domains cannot access the cookie anyway.  So - drop the cookie encryption, but do you still think it's a good idea to pass the password with each request?

Comment: Well yes, if you really need to be stateless then you're sending it with each request anyway, so why beat around the bush? Make sure you're on HTTPS and that the password only persists with the client window (whichever way you decide to do that but `window.name` isn't a good idea due to shoulder surfing).

Comment: @TildalWave So there's a lot more about security that I don't know than I do know, so please forgive this simple question.  Assuming I make the modifications you've suggested and just store the user id / pwd clear in a cookie and send them over https is the app secure or do I really need server side sessions with security tokens to be secure?

Comment: You're sending the password with either one at least once, so in that regard they're not any different. Sessions might make it easier to manage authorisation and it's easier to use more secure server-side password hashing since it doesn't cost you so many CPU cycles when using slow hashing algorithms only once per session, instead of on each request. You should still make sure you're secure against all other possible attacks, but that's rather a broad subject. I'd start with [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10) and work from there.

Comment: Ok, I'll read the OWASP Top 10 and go from there.  I'll eat the server CPU cycles hasing on every request.

Answer (score 1):

> Site-wide HTTPS

This is good.

> At registration to the service, the user's password is passed 'clear' to the server where it is stored in a salted sha-3 hash.

This is bad. Hash passwords with a slow password hashing algorithm like `pbkdf2`, `bcrypt` or `scrypt` instead.

> Upon login, the javascript client does not pass the user id and password to the server. Instead, it generates a random string and stores that in the window.name space. It then uses this string as a passphrase to perform 256bit AES encryption on the name and password, storing this cipher text in a cookie. This cookie has a life of 1 hour.
>
> Henceforth, all API calls require that the client access the window.name string, decrypt the cookie, and pass the username/password 'clear' to the server. A unix-epoch timestamp is also passed.
>
> The server, upon receiving any request, retrieves the user's salt, performs a sha-3 hash on the password, and compares it to the stored value in the db. It also ensures that the timestamp is within 60 seconds of the server time.

This looks overly complex to me. You can simply pass the username and password over HTTPS to the server during login. If the authentication succeeds, generate a random token on the server side and return it to the client. Any future request must include that token to be considered authenticated. You can invalidate the token after a certain period of time on the server side if needed.

Comment: Tho this requires tracking the tokens on the server side, which seemed to me to be a violation of a truly restful api.  This solution is definitely easier tho.

Comment: Also, passing hashed passwords mean that I would be revealing the type of hashing I use to protect passwords in my db, right?

Comment: @user36581 No, why pass hashed passwords? Hash them on the server side.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood you.  You were ok with passing the passwords clear, but you were recommending a different hashing algorithm.  Ok, yeah totally cool.  I'll hash on the server with one of the recommended algorithms.